# DLRS Relationship Criteria Error

Tags: roll-up-summary, dlrs

I am working on a DLRS and am not quite sure where I am going wrong. I keep getting an error on the Relationship Criteria fields. Here is the error message:

Error:

> Relationship Criteria: Relationship Criteria 'MAX (cv__Amount__c)' is not valid, see SOQL documentation http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm, error is 'unexpected token: ')''

Basically, I am trying to pull the primary (Maximum money going to it) accounting designation from a donation and have it appear on the donation record. For the where statement or Relationship Criteria - I am using:

```
MAX(cv_Amount__c)
```

And then the field in the relationship criteria fields is obviously `cv_Amount__c`. However its saying that is not valid. I've tried other variations but none work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your Relationship Criteria shouldn't include an aggregate operation. Define your aggregation with the Field to Aggregate and Aggregate Operation fields on your rollup summary definition.

If you're trying to find the maximum amount represented on a child object, you want the Aggregate Operation "Max" and the Field to Aggregate `cv_Amount__c`. This field must be on your child object.

If instead you want to select a *different* field on the child object that has the greatest `cv_Amount__c`, choose the Aggregate Operation "First" or "Last", populate `cv_Amount__c` in the Field to Order By field, and the name of the field whose value you want populated on the parent in the Field to Aggregate.

Your Relationship Criteria should define the criteria for selecting *which* child records you want to rollup. It must be substitutable into a SOQL `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I see! That makes sense, however I want to rollup the name of the accounting code that has the max amount of a donation designated to it, not just the amount itself.

Comment: Then you want the second of the two options above. Aggregate option "First" or "Last", ordering by the amount.

Comment: That is what I had originally tried and it did not work :(

Comment: In what way did it not work? How did you configure it? Did you receive an error?

Comment: There were no errors, but when I went to calculate the rollup, nothing happened.

Comment: I believe the configuration is correct. If you didn't receive any results, there could be a different issue - the Relationship Criteria might be mistaken, the mode might be set to user instead of system, visibility issues, and so on.

Comment: I am now getting results...in the form of errors in the Summary Log: OpportunityTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

() : CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY ()

Comment: That isn't related to DLRS. Your own org's OpportunityTrigger is broken. DLRS triggers have names starting with `dlrs_`.